# How do you not do partial mocking in this scenario?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, partial

Let's say I wrote a pretty simple class called `ValueFinder` that looks like this:

```
public class ValueFinder {

    public String findValue(Object obj) {
        String value = null;
        value = findValueFirstWay(obj);
        if (value == null) {
            value = findValueSecondWay(obj);
        }
        return value;
    }

    protected String findValueFirstWay(Object obj) {
        ....
    }

    protected String findValueSecondWay(Object obj) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Now I want to test that `findValueFirstWay` is really the first method attempted when calling `findValue`. This is a very simple class, the "algorithms" of the ways are very simple. Without doing a partial mock where `findValueFirstWay` and `findValueSecondWay` are mocked and `findValue` is left alone, how do I test that?

I assume I'm supposed to refactor the class so that `findValueFirstWay` and `findValueSecondWay` are in a separate class or classes? It just seems like unnecessary work for something so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid mocking entirely and test it by the visible effect with real objects.

Or you could mock the objects being passed in as values, and expect whatever calls that the `findValueFirstWay(Object obj)` makes to the `obj` that cause it to return a null, etc.

However, even though it seems simple, my first impulse would still be to extract the problem methods to a separate class or two, so that the interaction can be more naturally tested with mocks.

Comment: I think you are right, the class can fully be tested by just creating the right inputs and verifying the outputs with real object.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. You could use the strategy pattern and define a strategy class for each of the way, but it seems overkill in such a simple situation. I don't see anything wrong in using a partial mock to test this.

Comment: That's where my thinking is right now. There doesn't seem like there should be a hard rule on partial mocking. A lot of writing code comes to judgement and it seems like a judgement call on when to use and when using it is telling you that maybe you need to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply subclass `ValueFinder` for your test and override the two protected methods? This way you could keep track of what has been called in which order (using flags, variables, ..) without having to move the methods elsewhere. Though this would be some kind of "partial mocking", wouldn't it?

Comment: I had looked around and found the subclass and override method. I think that a partial mock is equivalent to a subclass but has the advantage that its much more succinct that defining the subclass.

Comment: @Ryan You are probably right about the distinction. A subclass makes more sense when complex logic is required. But why are you trying to avoid mocking? It seems to be the straight approach in the case where you are trying to test the one method in isolation.